# Recommended ETL Tool

Tags: open-source, database, business-intelligence

Goal:
Find a new [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool that shall replace [Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services).

Criteria:
- Open source, or free to use. No trial.
- User-friendly.

Information:
- I use different databases that is SQL server and postgreSQL to make some transaction.
- I need to make some data transaction between SQL server to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Talend ETL](http://www.talend.com/resource/extract-transform-load.html):

- free and open source. It was actually the first major open source ETL, founded in 2005.
- supports all major DBMSs like PostgreSQL, SQL server and so on.
- last time I use it a few years ago I and a few other friends who had tried found it pretty user-friendly (but it might be a bit biased as at that time I was in France and Talend was created by a bunch of French people):

[image]

Talend is the first open source solution in this [ranking](http://www.etltool.com/list-of-etl-tools/):

[image]

Comment: I have extensive experience in SSIS & based on my knowledge Talend is a tough competitor with a lot of feature. My upvote.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Pentaho](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/):

- free and open source
- supports all major DBMSs like PostgreSQL, [SQL server](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/MS+SQL+Server) and so on (even [NoSQL databases](http://www.pentahobigdata.com/ecosystem/platforms/nosql)).
- when I was reviewing ETL open source solutions a few years ago it was the most mentioned one along with Talend.
- UI pretty similar to Talend (Spoon is the design interface for building ETL jobs):

[image]