# Free alternative to DataRPM (Report Analysis for Big data)

Tags: open-source, data-analysis, reporting

I'm looking for a browser based FREE or OPEN-SOURCE alternative to DataRPM.

Data RPM is a software for discovering reports of information based on large data.
Saw a demo of the software some time ago, and thought there could be a free alternative to it, cause currently the software is quite costly!

I'm mostly looking for the best way (FREE or Less costly) for analyzing and report-generation of large BIG data sources!!

I mainly need this to get reports in sales and production. We have SAP, but that's not quite a user friendly software..... something that can take SAP data as the data source, and also take SQL-Server as the data source...

That's mostly all! If anyone knows about any open source software, then would there be any freelance website that supports customization of the open source software?

Thanks.
-MK.

Comment: How about [Recommended ETL Tool](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/5710/903)?

Comment: That's not browser based! It should be accessible via browser! That would prevent installing software on every computer required for viewing the data analysis... basically it could be installed on a server, and accessed via browser on the network! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pentaho (Community version)](http://community.pentaho.com/) will suit your purpose perfectly.

Pentaho has separate software programs for each aspect of BI (ETL, cubes creation, drilling/MDX, reports, dashboards, automation, etc).

Via any web browser you can:

- Select data sources, design OLAP cubes (I recommend the open source plugin [Saiku](http://www.meteorite.bi/saiku))
- Design reports and dashboards
- See the reports and dashboards

Each of the entities is free and Open Source.
It supports huge amounts of data.
You can [connect it with SAP](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Connecting+with+SAP+Systems), and of course SQL can be used as a source of data, among many others.

[image: Saiku]
[image: Pentaho web browser settings]
[image: Pentaho web browser]

It is free and open source.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this software would be fine!